# объединение данных c БД для вывода в Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Проект на ASP.NET MVC, электронный магазин. Есть метод в контроллере:

```
public ActionResult ShowOrder()
{

    var orders = storeDB.OrderDetails.ToList();


    return View(orders);
}
```

Есть вью, которая выводит результат:

```
@model List<MvcCosmeticsStore.Models.OrderDetail>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowOrder";
}
<h2>ShowOrder</h2>

@using GridMvc.Html
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
           {

               columns.Add(c => c.OrderId).Sortable(true).Titled("OrderId");
               columns.Add(c => c.Order.FirstName).Sortable(true).Titled("FirstName");
               columns.Add(c => c.Order.LastName).Sortable(true).Titled("LastName");
               columns.Add(c => c.Order.Address).Sortable(true).Titled("Address");
               columns.Add(c => c.Order.City).Sortable(true).Titled("City");
               columns.Add(c => c.Order.Country).Sortable(true).Titled("Country");
               columns.Add(c => c.Order.Email).Sortable(true).Titled("Email");
               columns.Add(c => c.UnitPrice).Sortable(true).Titled("UnitPrice");
               columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(o => @Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = o.OrderId }, ""));
           }).WithPaging(20)
```

Итог на экране:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как обьединить по OrderId данные, чтобы не дублироваться, а просто UnitPrice, чтобы общую смму выводил, а не по каждому продукту??
Заранее спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

не проверял

```
    var v = storeDB.OrderDetails
         .GroupBy(d => d.Name)
         .Select(
              s => new
              {
                   price = s.Sum(u => u.Price),
                   name = s.Key,
                   smth = s.Select(c => c.Smth).FirstOrDefault()//,
                   //etc...
              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! попробовала, но выдает не совместимость типов!

Comment: Контроллер:  public ActionResult ShowOrder()
           {
               var orders = storeDB.OrderDetails
         .GroupBy(d => d.OrderDetailId)
         .Select(
              s => new
              {
                   price = s.Sum(u => u.UnitPrice),
                   name = s.Key,
                   lastname = s.Select(c => c.Order.LastName)
              });
               orders.ToList();
               return View(orders);
        }

Comment: ошибка:http://i.imgur.com/w6tczRN.png

Comment: попробуйте lastname = s.Select(c => c.LastName).FirstOrDefault(). c.Order кажется здесь лишним. s.Key имеется ввиду поле, по готорому группируете. все остальные должны заканчиваться на .FirstOrDefault()